# Keep receiving /sbin/mingetty[14312]: tty1: No such file or directory errors

Tags: fedora

When I check my /var/log/secure I see the following:

```
Jan 19 01:52:21 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24176]: tty5: No such file or directory
Jan 19 01:52:21 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24178]: tty4: No such file or directory
Jan 19 01:52:22 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24197]: tty2: No such file or directory
Jan 19 01:52:22 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24198]: tty1: No such file or directory
Jan 19 01:52:22 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24200]: tty3: No such file or directory
Jan 19 01:52:23 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24207]: tty6: No such file or directory
Jan 19 01:52:26 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24249]: tty5: No such file or directory
Jan 19 01:52:26 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24250]: tty4: No such file or directory
Jan 19 01:52:27 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24264]: tty2: No such file or directory
Jan 19 01:52:27 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24265]: tty1: No such file or directory
Jan 19 01:52:27 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24266]: tty3: No such file or directory
Jan 19 01:52:28 205524 /sbin/mingetty[24271]: tty6: No such file or directory
```

Which keeps repeating every few seconds.

My /etc/inittab is empty except for:

```
id:3:initdefault:
```

I tried adding the following to /etc/inittab:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty1
2:2345:off:/sbin/mingetty tty2
3:2345:off:/sbin/mingetty tty3
4:2345:off:/sbin/mingetty tty4
5:2345:off:/sbin/mingetty tty5
6:2345:off:/sbin/mingetty tty6
```

I've tried manually creating the tty with:

mknod -m 644 /dev/tty1 c 5 0

and the error changes to:

/sbin/mingetty[28362]: tty1: cannot open tty: No such device or address

and

mknod /dev/tty1 c 4 1

and receive error:

/sbin/mingetty[3317]: tty1: cannot open tty: Permission denied

tried: chmod a+rw /dev/tty1
error: /sbin/mingetty[3756]: tty1: cannot open tty: Permission denied

Inside of inittab it says:

```
# Terminal gettys (tty[1-6]) are handled by /etc/event.d/tty[1-6] and
# /etc/event.d/serial
```

but I'm really lost as what to try next, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

uname -a
Linux servername 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5.028stab070.5 #1 SMP Fri Sep 17 19:10:36 MSD 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I'm not sure if it matters but this is on a vps server

Comment: It would be useful to know the contents of `/proc/devices`

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a vps server it probably has no virtual consoles and the devices don't exist. Check the /etc/event.d directory and delete/move the tty[1-6] from there.

Comment: There does not seem to be any /etc/event.d directory in Fedora.

Comment: The downvote is unjustified IMHO. Fedora 12 had /etc/events.d: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Installation_Guide/s2-boot-init-shutdown-init.html and http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Installation_Guide/s2-boot-init-shutdown-jobs.html and the question is tagged with fedora 12.

Comment: Even the question itself mentions /etc/event.d.

Comment: The uname -a output says that this is a 64-bit OpenVZ container on a 64-bit RHEL/CentOS host. AFAIK, on OpenVZ ttys are typically set up from the host, not inside the container, so I'd go along with the advice to look for and try removing the tty config lines.

Comment: You are correct, but in that case, that doesn't help, since /etc/init/tty.conf does not exist in el5. El5 is based on Fedora Core 6, and this one still uses /etc/inittab. So you'd have to comment out the line in /etc/inittab.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out all the lines in `/etc/init/tty.conf` and then `reboot`.

Comment: Only in Fedora 13 - 14 which had a newer upstart version. Fedora 15 and up use systemd.